# materializecss google apps responsive mobile font size

Tags: responsive-design, materialize, font-size

I have written a google web app using materializecss. All works well on a laptop. I have designed it to be responsive, testing by reducing the width of the browser on my laptop and again, it workds well.

But, when I try it on an actual android phone using chrome, it is correctly reducing the number of columns, but I can barely read the text as it is soo small. It looks like the screen is laptop width, with each of the input fields taking the full width. When I click on any field, it goes maximum zoom to somewhere on the page and I have to scroll around to find the field I have clicked on, then zoom out a little. Sorry I can't explain any more, its wierd.

I have created a simple test by copying the 'Getting Started' code and 'Text Input' code from the materialize website and exactly the same thing happens.

There's not a lot in the form-JS, I have just been trying some Materialize form inits.

It looks fine when you run it in the code snippet on in a browser on a laptop, but when you try it on a phone it goes all wrong.

```js
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //  M.updateTextFields();
    M.AutoInit();
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 l6">
              <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12 l6">
              <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input disabled value="I am not editable" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="disabled">Disabled</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
              This is an inline input field:
              <div class="input-field inline">
                <input id="email_inline" type="email" class="validate">
                <label for="email_inline">Email</label>
                <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Helper text</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- Close Container -->

    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the problem you describe when testing with the code you posted:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ExoegNJ

Maybe there's an issue related to this line
`<?!= include("form-JS"); ?>`

Are you able to post this form-js file as well?

[image: mobile screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this David. I have edited the original post and used code from the materialize website. Still hapenning! Not a lot in the JS file, but I have posted that. It doesn't make any difference though.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details Liam. Does https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ExoegNJ still not work for you? I'm not seeing any obvious problems on Chrome + iPhone. Screenshot attached

Comment: I have continued digging into this. Tried it on an iPad (safari) and it looks great. So I tried it back on android using both Firefox and Opera. It's still a little bit wide, but is very usable.

Comment: So it appears this is only hapenning when using Googles Web App on an Android using Google Chrome!

Comment: Hmmm, if it's looking like a web app + android issue I'm not sure if can take this any further Liam. I'm not able to test that. I think of anything I'll post it though.